# Service with WindowManager and Notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, android-windowmanager

I have a Service. I have used WindowManager to show some UI during the runtime of Service. Also I am showing notification during the lifetime of this Service.

**Below is my Service class**

```
public class DemoService extends Service implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final int mLayoutParamFlags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;

// Views
private View mDemoView;
private ImageButton mEndButton

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    showNotification();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mDemoView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.windowmanager_demo, null);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            mLayoutParamFlags,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    mEndButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.end_button);
    mEndButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.addView(mDemoView, params);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Remove notification
    stopForeground(true);
    // Remove WindowManager
    if(mDemoView != null){
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.removeView(mDemoView);
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.end_button:
            endService();
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Show notification
 */
private void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.demoicon)
            .setContentTitle("Demo App")
            .setContentText("Demo Message");

    startForeground(R.string.demo_string, notificationBuilder.build());
}

private void endService() {
    // Stop demo service
    stopSelf();
}
```

**Below are the things I want to implement but I don't know how**

1. When the service is running and WindowManager's UI is visible, if I press hardware back/home key, then WindowManager's UI should disappear while the service should keep running. I don't know how to capture back press in service.
2. When I click on the notification then the WindowManager's UI should become visible.

Please help me implement these 2 things.

Answer (score 2):

1. To catch the back key, extend the `ViewGroup` or `View` you are adding to the WindowManager, and override [`onKeyUp`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyUp(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)), or [`dispatchKeyEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)) (and check the keyCode and track `ACTION_UP`). Note that to ensure it works, you must check your [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) flags and it's type so your View is focusable (for example, with [`TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY), the window is unfocusable), **BUT** when your View is collapsed (if you do something like Facebook Messenger Chat Heads), you must update your View LayoutParams to put the flag [`FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE). If you fail to do this, pressing the back key won't be dispatched to the underlying Activity, but only to your window, which would make users uninstall your app.
2. When you add an action to a notification, you use a [`PendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). In a pendingIntent, you can add an explicit Intent. It can be a Service action (don't worry, your service can't be started twice, only `onStartCommand` will be called on the running instance, if already started), a BroadcastReceiver, or an Activity. Services actions is what you probably want, but you can also use BroadcastReceivers if appropriate.

Note that Marshmallow requires you to take the user to the Settings screen to let him manually enable the "Draw over other apps" permission for your app. You can find more info on the [Android Developers page on G+](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts), they posted about runtime permissions recently.